# Log Loss function in pyspark

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, cross-validation

Is there a built-in log loss function in pyspark?

I have a pyspark dataframe with columns: 
probability, rawPrediction, label

and I want to use mean log loss to evaluate these predictions.

Answer (score 8):

No such function exists directly, as far as I can tell. But given a PySpark dataframe `df` with the columns named as in the question, one can explicitly calculate the average log loss:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

eps = 1e-7
df_w_logloss = (
    df
    # clip predictions to within [eps, 1-eps] to prevent infinities
    .withColumn('prob_eps', f.least(f.greatest(f.col('probability'), f.lit(eps)), f.lit(1-eps)))
    .withColumn(
        'logloss',
        -f.col('label')*f.log(f.col('prob_eps')) - (1.-f.col('label'))*f.log(1.-f.col('prob_eps')),
    )
)
logloss = df_w_logloss.agg(f.mean('logloss').alias('ll')).collect()[0]['ll']
```

I'm assuming here that `label` is numerical (i.e. 0 or 1), and that `probability` represents the predictions of the model. (Not sure what `rawPrediction` might mean.)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are using Spark ML and that your dataframe is the output of a fitted estimator.  In this case, you can use the following function to calculate the log loss.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def log_loss(df):

  # extract predicted probability
  get_first_element = F.udf(lambda v:float(v[1]), FloatType())
  df = df.withColumn("preds", get_first_element(F.col("probability")))

  # calculate negative log-likelihood
  y1, y0 = F.col("label"), 1 - F.col("label")
  p1, p0 = F.col("preds"), 1 - F.col("preds")
  nll = -(y1*F.log(p1) + y0*F.log(p0))

  # aggregate
  return df.agg(F.mean(nll)).collect()[0][0]
```